# Register checked event handler for each checkbox in an auto generated column datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, event-handling

My end goal is to build a datagrid with auto generated columns (because I will never know exactly how many class properties will need to be generated). This datagrid will always have the first column as a checkbox. If a user selects multiple rows in the datagrid, and then checks one of the selected checkboxes, all of the checkboxes (in the first column, or associated column - either is fine) will also be checked.

I've experimented with using a DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate in xaml like so:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="SheetListGrid"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  HeadersVisibility="All"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="SheetListGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">

            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

But I had trouble getting multiple checkboxes to switch to checked at once. 
My second attempt was to remove the DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate completely, and place this in a DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn event handler like so:
Edit: The main purpose of this was to add my own checkbox column and be able to single click the checkbox state.

```
  private void SheetListGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column is DataGridCheckBoxColumn && !e.Column.IsReadOnly)
        {
            FrameworkElementFactory checkboxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
            checkboxFactory.SetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
            checkboxFactory.SetValue(VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center);
            checkboxFactory.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding(e.PropertyName) { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

            e.Column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
            {
                Header = e.Column.Header,
                CellTemplate = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = checkboxFactory },
                SortMemberPath = e.Column.SortMemberPath
            };

            // notice I tried registering the event handler here as well.
            // but this caused a continuous loop of CheckBox_Checked to be 
            // fired.
            // register the checkbox event handler
            //checkboxFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CheckBox_Checked));
        }
    }
```

Here is my CheckBox_Checked event handler in case that is useful...

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get the selected sheets
        var selectedSheets = SheetListGrid.SelectedItems;

        if (selectedSheets.Count == 0) return;

        foreach (var item in selectedSheets)
        {
            //DataGridRow row = SheetListGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;

            FakeSheet sheet = item as FakeSheet;
            if (sheet.Selected == false)
                sheet.Selected = true;
        }
        SheetListGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

I feel as if I am missing something to make this a whole lot easier, but I can't figure it out and I've nearly melted my RAM from the amount of tabs I have open. I should note that this project will be a class library, and I cannot include any third party assemblies. Additional, I would like to try and avoid using Windows.Interactivity as I've had issues with distributing this class library to others before, and there computer running a separate version which caused errors.

Comment: Is this what you need - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497537/event-for-select-all-wpf-datagrid

Comment: I don't believe so. What this SO link seems to be talking about is a "Select All" function. I'm looking for more of a "Check only the ones with rows selected".